# How do I retain an object within function

Tags: loops, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a function that creates an object and then loops through and binds everything together. The error I've found is that:

> In rm(long) : object 'long' not found

long appears to cease existing between its creation and the loop. This is probably a fairly basic gap in my knowledge of how functions work.Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code I use is below.

```
Test <- FunctionName(Variables = c("Name"))


FunctionName <- function(Variables) {
var_list <- paste0("|._", c("Variables"), collapse = "")
var_list <- paste0("Pim", var_list)

long <- read_dta(file=paste0("a_dataname.dta")) %\>%
select(matches(var_list)) %>%
rename_at(vars(starts_with("a_")), ~str_replace(., "a_", "")) %>%
mutate(wave=1)

for (wn in 2:3) {
w1 <- paste0(letters[wn],"_")
wave_data <- read_dta(paste0(w1, "dataname.dta")) %>%
select(matches(var_list)) %>%
rename_at(vars(starts_with(w1)), ~str_replace(.,w1, "")) %\>%
mutate(wave = wn) %>% print()
Final <- bind_rows(long, wave_data)
rm(long)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see multiple things.

1. `rm(long)` inside the `for` loop

`long` is removed in the first iteration of the loop and in the next iteration, you get an error message. You should put `rm(long)` outside the loop at the end of your function. But actually, you do not need to remove variables that are created inside a function. Because they are not created in the global environment, but in an environment that only the function can "see".

2. `Final` is not stored

I assume `Final` is an object intented to store and return the results of the `for` loop.

```r
Final <- bind_rows(long, wave_data)
```

is rewriting Final with each iteration as a combination of `long` + the current `wave_data`. At the end of the loop, `Final` will only contain results of the last iteration, everything else was overwritten. There are numerous answers on how to store results from within a `for` loop.

3. Your function does not return anything

You probably want that your function returns some data frame(s). In order to achieve this, you can look up how to make functions return something.